# VBA Macro in Excel 2010 deletes blank rows on the spreadsheet but I need row formulas to update

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

My request was to make a simple way for even a non-Excel user to delete blank rows on a report that needs to be run on multiple individuals. I used a Macro that deletes the blank rows. This works fine.

The issue now is that it only works once. If we change the individual the report stays blank. I have determined it is an issue with the row formulas and how the data is migrated from other parts of the workbook.

This workbook was not built by me so I have changed the formulas and done everything I can think of to get this report to be able to be updated with new names and have it work properly. I am stuck.

This is one of the formulas as it looked when I got the workbook:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Master Data'!$B2,'RGC2'!$B$1)),'Master Data'!D2,"")
```

It works great does what it is supposed to do but as an example if there are 50 rows to go through when my macro runs it deletes all blank rows but that formula above instead of shifting to reference chronologically the new rows I am left with (as an example):

```
Row 1 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Master Data'!$B2,'RGC2'!$B$1)),'Master Data'!D2,"")

Row 2 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Master Data'!$B35,'RGC2'!$B$1)),'Master Data'!D35,"")

Row 3 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Master Data'!$B47,'RGC2'!$B$1)),'Master Data'!D47,"")
```

So yes the rows are working and picking the correct individual but if we save then update to a new individual those row formulas have not updated so they can not find the new individual to populate the report with.

I have tried changing the formulas, removing the $ so it doesn't restrict to specific points...this is probably a simple thing that I am just lost on. I am sorry to have to ask for help but I do want this to work for the long term and not just once.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code? The formulas are not likely to be the main culprit, but something in the VBA sub.

Comment: A very useful shortcut to delete rows might be useful for your users:
Shift+Space  THEN CTRL+-

Answer (score 0):

When you delete rows, you only delete that specific row.  Formulas in other rows on the same sheet will not be affected.

Perhaps the solution to your problem is hiding rows instead of deleting them.
(I say perhaps, since I am not completely sure I understand your problem).